# Windows Phone 8.1 WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to get a Windows Phone 8.1 app to authenticate with google services. I'm trying the [code provided here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#windows-phone-81), but having a problem.

**IContinuationActivatedEventArgs** and **WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs** cannot be found.  MSDN says they should be in the using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation namespace, but adding that does not resolve the problem.  I've tried rebuilding the solution and cannot find anything else...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to add the *CintinuationManager* - [the complete code you can find here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone hits this issue.  I had the code in a shared location of a universal project.  That library wasn't being recognized by the Window's app.